# Texture features for pixel classification

Tags: python, feature-selection, image-processing

Is it possible to use texture features for pixel-by-pixel classification? I have used HOG or LBP for whole images but I am not sure how to handle single pixels. Can I simply add a gabor filter on my image and extract the corresponding class pixels at a certain position of the image from it and use it for training?

How to proceed in case of histograms like LPB, GLCM or HOG? Are there any other options if I have only labeled pixels and not entire images?

Comment: Could you do pixel classification based on the patch surrounding the pixel?

Comment: I think yes (I am new to this topic) and it somehow makes more sense for me then on a single pixel RGB features but I am not sure whether this is the correct way of doing it. I have millions of x, y positions of images with the corresponding classes and I want to predict a class of each pixels in new images.

Comment: I am also looking for good references or books, for whole image analysis I can find a lots of information but if it comes to pixels I can not find many useful informations...

Comment: Try looking into segmentation methods.  Many of these methods classify pixels as object/not object so they may work for your application.

Comment: The texture of images is not something that can be described in one single pixel. Pixels only have colors. A segment of image can be described using some textures such as Gradient, Entropy, Dimension, etc. So, I think you should segment your image. That can be done using a grid (hence, grid-based segmentation) or a clustering method to segment different areas/objects. Either way, you will be to summarize your image using its texture features.